# httpuv fails to start oauth server when running batch file via Task Scheduler

Tags: r, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, r-googlesheets

I have a batch file that kicks off an R script:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:\Folder\Script.R"
```

Within this R script, I use the `gs_auth` function to grab my auth token and use it in the R session. I can successfully run my R script by double-clicking on the batch file from Folder Explorer, and everything runs perfectly.

When I set up a Task Scheduler task to run the batch file, I instead get the following error:

```
Error in httpuv::startServer(use$host, use$port, list(call = listen)) :
  Failed to create server
Calls: gs_title ... init_oauth2.0 -> oauth_authorize -> oauth_listener -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I have tried 'Running with highest privileges' in Task Scheduler and also entered my Windows password, but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I am missing in terms of loading the token?

---

Code

The commented out lines are there because they show the initialisation steps to 'bake' the token so that I can use it later on. These steps were followed as per [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/vignettes/managing-auth-tokens.html#where-do-tokens-live-in-between-r-sessions).

```
##Need to run gs_auth line only because need to paste stuff in from IE
#token <- gs_auth(cache = FALSE)
#gd_token()
##Bake token to working directory
#saveRDS(token, file = "googlesheets_token.rds")

setwd("C:/Folder")
gs_auth(token = "googlesheets_token.rds")

for_gs <- gs_title("data_log")
for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(for_gs)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2018-08-18T15:11:51.0347984</Date>
    <Author>abc-PC\User</Author>
    <URI>\ozb</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-2866463773-2659414307-4023886308-1002</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
  </Settings>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2018-08-18T15:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT15M</Interval>
      </Repetition>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"C:\Folder\run_it.bat"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: There maybe other process that is listening on same port.(1410). at command prompt type `netstat -a -n -o|findstr ":1410"` to see if the port in use

Comment: Don't post screen shot images when you can simply cut and past the content into you post. Images are not searchable.

Comment: For task scheduler related issues, always include the XML configuration exported from the task scheduler app.

Comment: Updated with text instead of screenshot and XML

Comment: Appears to be working now.